# Kivy set size_hint_x to size_hint_y

Tags: python, kivy

Using kivy, is there a way to set the size_hint_x property to size_hint_y?
Here is my code:

```py
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: "right"
    anchor_y: "bottom"
    Button:
        size_hint_y: 0.2
        size_hint_x: size_hint_y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your kv code to:

```
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: "right"
    anchor_y: "bottom"
    Button:
        id: btn
        size_hint_y: 0.2
```

and add this code:

```py
def your_function_in_root_class(self):
    size_y = self.ids.btn.size_hint_y
    self.ids.btn.size_hint_x = size_y
```